# java gui method/object calls

Tags: java, user-interface, object, methods

Below I have two code sections. The first performs the operation I want from the second. The first code compiles and works correctly and the second does not. I am new to java and think I am missing something basic on how to recall another object label or spinner.
I want a method that does all the things in the spinner state change. I am open to all good practice implementations. I am using window Builder in eclipse.

```
package stackoverflowtestgui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;        

public class TestGUI {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestGUI window = new TestGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("total: "+total);
        lblTotal.setBounds(31, 38, 101, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTotal);

        JSpinner spinner_2 = new JSpinner();
        JSpinner spinner_1 = new JSpinner();
        spinner_2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                num1 = (double) spinner_1.getValue();
                num2 = (double) spinner_2.getValue();
                total = num1+num2;
                lblTotal.setText("total: "+total);
            }
        });
        spinner_2.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(new Double(0), null, null, new Double(1)));
        spinner_2.setBounds(31, 73, 30, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(spinner_2);


        spinner_1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                num1 = (double) spinner_1.getValue();
                num2 = (double) spinner_2.getValue();
                total = num1+num2;
                lblTotal.setText("total: "+total);
            }
        });
        spinner_1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(new Double(0), null, null, new Double(1)));
        spinner_1.setBounds(31, 104, 30, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(spinner_1);
    }
public double num1=0;
public double num2=0;
public double total=0;
}
```

Here is an example of how I the code to do what i wanted :)

```
package stackoverflowtestgui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class TestGUI {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestGUI window = new TestGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestGUI() {

        initialize();

    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        lblTotal.setBounds(31, 38, 101, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblTotal);

        spinner_2.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                newmethod();
            }
        });

        spinner_2.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(new Double(0), null, null, new Double(1)));
        spinner_2.setBounds(31, 73, 72, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(spinner_2);


        spinner_1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                newmethod();
            }
        });

        spinner_1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(new Double(0), null, null, new Double(1)));
        spinner_1.setBounds(31, 104, 72, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(spinner_1);
    }
    protected void newmethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        num1 = (double) spinner_1.getValue();
        num2 = (double) spinner_2.getValue();
        total = num1+num2;
        lblTotal.setText("total: "+total);
    }
public double num1=0;
public double num2=0;
public double total=0;
public JSpinner spinner_2 = new JSpinner();
public JSpinner spinner_1 = new JSpinner();
public JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("total: ");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate on " second does not". What is the expected behaviour? What happens instead? What are error messages if any, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have declared variables spinner_1, spinner_2, and lblTotal as local variables in the initialize() method, so they are  not visible outside that method. they should be private instance variables of the class instead.

Comment: making them public like below worked
public double num1=0;
public double num2=0;
public double total=0;
public JSpinner spinner_2 = new JSpinner();
public JSpinner spinner_1 = new JSpinner();
public JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("total: ");

Comment: Making the variables public is usually frowned upon, since it allows other classes to arbitrarily change any variable, which may lead to an inconsistent state. For example, `window.total=33.2;` changes the total, but the spinners still show the original values, which do not add up to that total..